# What do each of the files do inside of an iPhoto Library?

Tags: mac, photos.app

Inside my iPhoto library, there are many files and directories.

```
-rw-r--r--@  1 kevin  staff   3.9M Jul 10 21:10 AlbumData.xml
drwxr-xr-x   2 kevin  staff    68B Dec 23  2013 Attachments
drwxr-xr-x   2 kevin  staff    68B Dec 23  2013 Auto Import
drwxr-xr-x  21 kevin  staff   714B Jul 10 21:10 Database
-rw-r--r--@  1 kevin  staff   324B Dec 23  2013 Info.plist
drwxr-xr-x   3 kevin  staff   102B Jan  9  2014 Masters
drwxr-xr-x   3 kevin  staff   102B Jan  9  2014 Previews
-rw-r--r--@  1 kevin  staff   341B Dec 23  2013 ProjectDBVersion.plist
-rw-r--r--@  1 kevin  staff   576K Jul 10 21:10 Projects.db
drwxr-xr-x   4 kevin  staff   136B Jan  9  2014 Thumbnails
drwxr-xr-x   4 kevin  staff   136B Jul 10 21:10 iLifeShared
-rw-r--r--@  1 kevin  staff     1B Jul 10 21:10 iPhotoLock.data
drwxr-xr-x@ 55 kevin  staff   1.8K Jul  7 10:00 iPod Photo Cache
```

Inside the `Database` folder:

```
drwxr-xr-x  801 kevin  staff    27K Jul 10 21:10 Albums
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 kevin  staff    18B Dec 23  2013 BigBlobs.apdb -> apdb/BigBlobs.apdb
-rw-r--r--@   1 kevin  staff   2.4K Jul 10 21:10 DataModelVersion.plist
drwxr-xr-x    6 kevin  staff   204B Dec 23  2013 Faces
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 kevin  staff    13B Dec 23  2013 Faces.db -> apdb/Faces.db
drwxr-xr-x  800 kevin  staff    27K Jul 10 21:10 Folders
drwxr-xr-x    3 kevin  staff   102B Dec 23  2013 History
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 kevin  staff    17B Dec 23  2013 History.apdb -> apdb/History.apdb
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 kevin  staff    22B Dec 23  2013 ImageProxies.apdb -> apdb/ImageProxies.apdb
-rw-r--r--@   1 kevin  staff   1.5K May 21 18:22 Keywords.plist
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 kevin  staff    17B Dec 23  2013 Library.apdb -> apdb/Library.apdb
drwxr-xr-x    2 kevin  staff    68B Dec 23  2013 Places
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 kevin  staff    20B Dec 23  2013 Properties.apdb -> apdb/Properties.apdb
-rw-r--r--@   1 kevin  staff    42B Mar 15 20:31 SpanCache.plist
drwxr-xr-x    2 kevin  staff    68B Dec 23  2013 Vaults
drwxr-xr-x    3 kevin  staff   102B Jan  9  2014 Versions
drwxr-xr-x    3 kevin  staff   102B May 21 18:21 Volumes
drwxr-xr-x    9 kevin  staff   306B Jul 10 21:10 apdb
-rw-r--r--@   1 kevin  staff   304B Jul 10 21:10 tmSync.plist
```

What parts of iPhoto are these files and directories responsible for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Basically, all the files like `xml, db` and such help different softwares like iPhoto, iMovies etc gain information about your photos.**

**Excerpted from [Fat Cat Software: iPhoto Library Internals](http://www.fatcatsoftware.com/iplm/Help/iphoto%20library%20internals.html) help page:**

> **AlbumData.xml**
>
> This file is written out by iPhoto as a way for other applications
>   (such as iMovie and iDVD) to be able to easily access the contents of
>   your iPhoto library. You can read in more detail about this file here.
>
> **AlbumData2.xml**
>
> This file is only created by iPhoto 8. It is a smaller version of the
>   AlbumData.xml file that only contains information for the library's
>   albums and events, and none of the actual photos. This file is faster
>   to read for programs that only need to get the list of albums and
>   events in the library.
>
> **Attachments**
>
> This folder is used by iPhoto 9 as a temporary holding place for
>   photos that are being sent using iPhoto's built-in email features.
>
> **Auto Import**
>
> This folder is created by iPhoto 7 and later. There does not seem to
>   be any mention of this folder in iPhoto's documentation, but if you
>   put some photos into it, then quit and reopen iPhoto, it will
>   automatically import those photos into the iPhoto library and then
>   delete them from the Auto Import folder. There is also an "auto
>   import" Applescript command which does not appear to do anything when
>   called. It's not clear if this was a planned feature for iPhoto 7 that
>   ended up getting pulled out (but not completely, apparently), and it
>   doesn't seem to be very useful for anything, especially since that
>   folder is buried inside a package now, but that's what it does if
>   anyone is curious.
>
> **Backup**
>
> If a library has been upgraded from an earlier version of iPhoto to
>   iPhoto 9, a copy of the original database files from the library are
>   stored in this folder before performing the upgrade.
>
> **Caches**
>
> Only present in iPhoto 8 or later, this folder contains additional
>   data for the iPhoto library. Unlike some other Caches folders that can
>   be safe to delete, this one is not, so don't go deleting it in an
>   attempt to clear up disk space.
>
> **com.apple.iPhoto.plist**
>
> This file is actually not written out by iPhoto itself, but rather by
>   iPhoto Library Manager. It is a copy of the preferences file that is
>   associated with this library. When you switch between different iPhoto
>   libraries, iPhoto Library Manager will swap out this preference file
>   for the existing preferences before opening the library up.
>
> **Contents/PkgInfo**
>
> This is part of the new package structure in iPhoto 7 that gives the
>   package a type and creator code so that the Finder knows what
>   application the package belongs to.
>
> **face.db, face_blob.db**
>
> Contains the data for faces identified by the face recognition feature
>   added in iPhoto 8.
>
> **iLifeShared**
>
> Starting in iPhoto 9, the AlbumData2.xml file is now stored within
>   this folder rather than at the root level of the library package.
>
> **Info.plist**
>
> iPhoto 9 added this file, containing basic version information about
>   the library
>
> **iPhoto.ipspot**
>
> This file is written out by iPhoto and read in by Spotlight in order
>   to index the information about the photos in your photo library. You
>   must have iPhoto 5.0.2 or later for this file to be present.
>
> **iPhotoLock.data**
>
> This file is used by iPhoto to help prevent more than one copy of
>   iPhoto from accessing the library at one time.
>
> **iPod Photo Cache**
>
> This folder is created by iTunes if you choose to sync your iPhoto
>   library with a photo capable iPod. It contains cached information
>   about the last time the photos were synced and help speed up the
>   syncing process, allowing iTunes to tell which photos have changed
>   since the last sync and only update those ones. You can delete it if
>   you want to clear up space, but iTunes will have to create it all over
>   again the next time you sync your iPod's photos.
>
> **Library.data, Dir.data (iPhoto 2), Library.iPhoto, iPhoto.db (iPhoto 4, & 5), Library.iPhoto6 (iPhoto 6 & 7), iPhotoMain.db, iPhotoAux.db
>   (iPhoto 8), Database (iPhoto 9)**
>
> These files/folders serve as the central database where iPhoto stores
>   your library information. All your event, album, and photo metadata is
>   stored in these files.
>
> **Data, Originals, and Modified**
>
> iPhoto 6 organizes its photos fairly differently that previous
>   versions. Imported photos will initially be stored inside the
>   "Originals" folder. Within that folder, photos are organized into
>   subfolders based on the roll that they are in, so each roll gets its
>   own folder. Those rolls are then sorted by date (2006, 2005, etc.) and
>   put into dated folders accordingly. So, if you had a photo in a roll
>   named "Vacation" and dated February 24, 2004, to find that photo, go
>   into the "Originals" folder, then into "2004", then into the folder
>   named "Vacation". When you edit a photo in iPhoto, the original stays
>   where it is, and the edited photo is placed in the "Modified" folder,
>   which has the same per-roll organization scheme within it as the
>   "Originals" folder does. The "Data" folder contains all the scaled
>   down thumbnail version of photos in your library. If you upgrade to
>   iPhoto 6 from a previous version, iPhoto will rearrange all your
>   photos from the old scheme into the new scheme. After upgrading, you
>   may still see one or more leftover folders named "2004" and such.
>   These folders should no longer contain any files being used by iPhoto
>   6, and can be disposed of safely.
>
> **Thumbnails, Masters, and Previews**
>
> iPhoto 9 organizes photos in much the same way as iPhoto 6-8, but uses
>   the folder names Thumbnails, Masters, and Previews instead of Data,
>   Originals, and Modified
>
> **Metadata Backup**
>
> Created by iPhoto 8, containing backup copies of the metadata for your
>   photos, events, albums, and other library content. This information
>   can be used by iPhoto to recover a library whose main database has
>   been corrupted.
>
> **ProjectDBVersion.plist, Projects.db, Projects.db-journal, SharingActivity.db**
>
> These additional data files exist only in iPhoto 9 and contain
>   information relating to "keepsake" items such as books and slideshows,
>   and information for albums published on MobileMe, Flickr, or Facebook.
>
> **ThemeCache**
>
> A cache file used by iPhoto to store theme data used to make books,
>   calendars, and cards
>
> **Thumb32Segment.data, Thumb64Segment.data, ThumbJPGSegment.data**
>
> In order to improve performance, when you add photos to your library,
>   iPhoto creates small "thumbnail" versions of your photos and caches
>   them in these files. In iPhoto 5 and earlier, these files are instead
>   called Thumb32.data, Thumb64.data, and ThumbJPG.data.

**Note that there are some small and some large differences in the folder structure depending on what version of iPhoto you're using.**